# Which udev-attributes are really available during hot-/cold-plug?

Tags: linux, udev, wlan

Udev is hard to debug. – The virgin environment during system boot always deviates at least a little from the environment during a later re-run.

Thus, I’m trying to write udev-rules with the understanding of udev instead of trial-and-error.

One big problem is: **Which udev-attributes are available during hot-/cold-plug?**

The confusion comes from these two commands:

```
udevadm test /sys/class/net/wlx801f024ddc32
udevadm info --attribute-walk --path=/sys/class/net/wlx801f024ddc32
```

Both, for example, list `SUBSYSTEM`, which I know is available for udev-rules. But only the former has `DEVTYPE` (at least for wlan devices), while only the latter has `KERNEL`.

I actually need DEVTYPE (being “wlan”) during boot, but it seems not available when the rules kick in...

Comment: You could try `sudo udevadm trigger ...` as the man says it is "used to replay events at system coldplug time".

Comment: I see nothing with `udevadm trigger`. – Doesn’t make it easy to debug...

Answer (score 4):

Here is my understanding:

- `udevadm info -a` : shows the attributes `ATTRS{}` and the device hierarchy.
- `udevadm test` : shows the `ENV{}` variables during udev processing.

They do not show the same type of information. Your DEVTYPE variable may exist and should be tested as `ENV{DEVTYPE}=="wlan"`. However, it should be taken into account that ENV{} variables are created progressively during the udev processing. Therefore, the order of your rule matters and it should appear after `ENV{DEVTYPE}` has been created by another rule.

You can analyze the file 'udev_actions.txt' from the command below in order to deduce how things are ordered. Then you can decide the best number for your '.rules' file in order to test `ENV{DEVTYPE}`.

```
$ sudo udevadm test $DEVPATH 1> udev_ENV.txt 2> udev_actions.txt
```